# The meaning of "orifice" in a line from a show

Tags: meaning

I was watching "The Office" show. The Vice and the head of one departments are deciding on a health plan. The Vice argues for choosing the cheapest plan, and the manager responds: It's not gonna be a popular decision around **the old orifice**.

What does orifice mean here?

Comment: It's a common jocular term for "office".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Orifice* can refer, amongst other things, to a hole in the body such as the anus or vagina. It is therefore funny to hear the word if you are about eight years old.

It is also funny when someone accidentally uses the wrong word in place of one that sounds similar. This is called a [malapropism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism).

Michael's problem here is that it is not so funny when he deliberately and blatantly uses a word that sounds like *office* and when that word is totally inappropriate in an office context. He thinks it is funny to accidentally-on-purpose insert this word into the orifice dialogue, but we just cringe at his attempt at a joke.

Answer (score 0):

The manager (Michael ;)) is making an extremely childish joke, as he is prone to do, that doesn't make any intrinsic sense. His use of orifice in this joke is simply based on the fact that orifice can mean an opening or hole in the body. He's essentially saying butthole and laughing.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orifice